# Html5 Canvas method isPointInPath determines only the last object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

An example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sfsd6/2/).

```
var context=document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

//Red Box
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle="Red";
context.rect(10,10,50,50);
context.fill();

//Pink circle
context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth="3";
context.fillStyle="Pink";
context.arc(250,250,50,0,Math.PI*2,false);
context.fill();
context.stroke();

context.font="1.2em Verdana";
context.fillStyle="Black";
context.fillText(context.isPointInPath(35,35),35,35);
context.fillText(context.isPointInPath(250,250),250,250);
```

If you write without beginPath all objects detected.
How to identify objects on the canvas or to omit beginPath?

Comment: +1 for a simple, elegant, and properly pared-down test case explaining your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use that function you need to rebuild the path every time you want to do the test (just don't call `fill` or `stroke`).

What I do normally instead is using my own point-in-polygon test function or my own spatial data structure if there are a lot of objects and speed is important.

Note that a canvas is just a bitmap and it doesn't store the commands you use to draw on it. That is why it cannot do the check after drawing a shape and you can test only the current path.

Once you call `beginPath` the previous path geometry is discarded and what you have are only the affected pixels if you called `fill` or `stroke`.

May be for your case it may make sense to check the color of the canvas pixel...

Comment: I had a similar need in my code and, as suggested by 6502, I stored the points in my own data structure and used my own point-in-polygon function for hit testing. The canvas API really doesn't support non-trivial hit testing.

Comment: ...or you may want to consider using a retained graphics mode API like SVG instead of `<canvas>`, where hit testing is handled for you. You can still composite `<canvas>` as needed for per-pixel effects.

Answer (score 2):

I've just read that a new addition to the canvas specification is Path() objects. Presumably these could be stored and subsequently tested and/or replayed. Could be useful. If I've understood the spec correctly.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#path-objects

Comment: Yes with the new Path2D object, paths can now be stored as variables. See this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28913470